# XMLHttpRequest is working with IE8 but not with google chrome

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, google-chrome

Following code is working fine with IE8 but is not working with google chrome. What i need to add/modify in the code to make it work with chrome also. I have heard of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing.

```
function clickMe()
{

    var xmlHttp = null;
   var Url = "http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/gethint.asp?q=u";
    //var Url = "file:///D:/Durgesh/test.html";
    xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();    
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function()
    {

        if ( xmlHttp.readyState == 4 )
        {
                alert("status Code: " + xmlHttp.status);
            if ( xmlHttp.responseText == "Not found" )
            {
                alert("Not Found");
            }
            else
            {
                alert(xmlHttp.responseText);
            }
        }
    }
    xmlHttp.open( "GET", Url, true );
    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*'); 
    xmlHttp.send( null );

}
```

Comment: I don't see any CORS response headers when I look at the Network tab in Chrome's dev tools.

Answer (score 0):

Access-Control-Allow-Origin must be server side. ;)

Comment: but when i am using advance rest client for http get method in chrome, i am getting the response. How do that app is capturing the response? And m able to caplture using the same in IE. Just want to know how to capture in chrome.